# Can I use iPhone 4 3G services outside of my native country?

Tags: iphone, cellular-data

I have an iPhone 4, bought at my home country and I have a data plan with a local telco carrier. My phone has never [being unlocked](http://ipod.about.com/od/ipodiphonehardwareterms/g/unlocked_def.htm). See, I am such a nice citizen in Apple's walled, seclusive and closed Kingdom!

Now, I want to travel overseas and I am prepared to get a local sim card with 3G data plan wherever I go. My question is, can I use iPhone 4 with 3G services? What should I do to do so? Do I have to unlock my phone first? Will that render my warranty invalid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UK uses the GSM 900 / GSM 1800 MHz bands. These are, among others, supported by the GSM iPhone 4.

From the iPhone 4 - Technical Specifications page:

> GSM model: UMTS/HSDPA/HSUPA (850, 900, 1900, 2100 MHz); GSM/EDGE (850, 900, 1800, 1900 MHz)

These bands should give you coverage in most of the world, providing that you get a simcard from a GSM provider:

[GSM World Coverage](http://www.worldtimezone.com/gsm.html)

[image: GSM World Coverage map]

Comment: Thanks, but do I have to unlock my phone first?

Comment: Missed that part, sorry. Yes, you'll probably have to. The phone is locked to only use the network of your current provider, so if you want to use it on any other network (local or abroad) you'll have to unlock it.